Failure to get road network from OSMNX
I've been using OSMNX for a couple of years now. Recently, I've started getting this error intermittently.
Here is an example.
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon_coords = [
    (-74.0358, 40.7499), 
    (-74.0358, 40.7351), 
    (-74.0238, 40.7351), 
    (-74.0238, 40.7499),
    (-74.0358, 40.7499)  
]
polygon = Polygon(polygon_coords)

G=  ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type='drive',simplify=False)

overpass endpoint configured: https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    788 # Make the request on the HTTPConnection object
--> 789 response = self._make_request(
    790     conn,
    791     method,
    792     url,
    793     timeout=timeout_obj,
    794     body=body,
    795     headers=headers,
    796     chunked=chunked,
    797     retries=retries,
    798     response_conn=response_conn,
    799     preload_content=preload_content,
    800     decode_content=decode_content,
    801     **response_kw,
    802 )
    804 # Everything went great!

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:490, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    489         new_e = _wrap_proxy_error(new_e, conn.proxy.scheme)
--> 490     raise new_e
    492 # conn.request() calls http.client.*.request, not the method in
    493 # urllib3.request. It also calls makefile (recv) on the socket.

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:466, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    465 try:
--> 466     self._validate_conn(conn)
    467 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1095, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1094 if conn.is_closed:
-> 1095     conn.connect()
   1097 # TODO revise this, see https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2791

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:730, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    728 server_hostname_rm_dot = server_hostname.rstrip(".")
--> 730 sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
    731     sock=sock,
    732     cert_reqs=self.cert_reqs,
    733     ssl_version=self.ssl_version,
    734     ssl_minimum_version=self.ssl_minimum_version,
    735     ssl_maximum_version=self.ssl_maximum_version,
    736     ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
    737     ca_cert_dir=self.ca_cert_dir,
    738     ca_cert_data=self.ca_cert_data,
    739     cert_file=self.cert_file,
    740     key_file=self.key_file,
    741     key_password=self.key_password,
    742     server_hostname=server_hostname_rm_dot,
    743     ssl_context=self.ssl_context,
    744     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    745     assert_hostname=self.assert_hostname,
    746     assert_fingerprint=self.assert_fingerprint,
    747 )
    748 self.sock = sock_and_verified.socket

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:909, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(sock, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ssl_minimum_version, ssl_maximum_version, cert_file, key_file, key_password, ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data, assert_hostname, assert_fingerprint, server_hostname, ssl_context, tls_in_tls)
    907         server_hostname = normalized
--> 909 ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    910     sock=sock,
    911     keyfile=key_file,
    912     certfile=cert_file,
    913     key_password=key_password,
    914     ca_certs=ca_certs,
    915     ca_cert_dir=ca_cert_dir,
    916     ca_cert_data=ca_cert_data,
    917     server_hostname=server_hostname,
    918     ssl_context=context,
    919     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    920 )
    922 try:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:469, in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    467 context.set_alpn_protocols(ALPN_PROTOCOLS)
--> 469 ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    470 return ssl_sock

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    511     return SSLTransport(sock, ssl_context, server_hostname)
--> 513 return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dummy_folder\lib\ssl.py:513, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    507 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    508                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    509                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    510                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    511     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    512     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 513     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    514         sock=sock,
    515         server_side=server_side,
    516         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    517         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    518         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    519         context=self,
    520         session=session
    521     )

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dummy_folder\lib\ssl.py:1071, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1070             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1071         self.do_handshake()
   1072 except (OSError, ValueError):

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dummy_folder\lib\ssl.py:1342, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1341         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1342     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1343 finally:

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:667, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    666 try:
--> 667     resp = conn.urlopen(
    668         method=request.method,
    669         url=url,
    670         body=request.body,
    671         headers=request.headers,
    672         redirect=False,
    673         assert_same_host=False,
    674         preload_content=False,
    675         decode_content=False,
    676         retries=self.max_retries,
    677         timeout=timeout,
    678         chunked=chunked,
    679     )
    681 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:843, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    841     new_e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", new_e)
--> 843 retries = retries.increment(
    844     method, url, error=new_e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    845 )
    846 retries.sleep()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py:474, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    473 if read is False or method is None or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 474     raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    475 elif read is not None:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py:38, in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     37 if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
---> 38     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     39 raise value

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, preload_content, decode_content, **response_kw)
    788 # Make the request on the HTTPConnection object
--> 789 response = self._make_request(
    790     conn,
    791     method,
    792     url,
    793     timeout=timeout_obj,
    794     body=body,
    795     headers=headers,
    796     chunked=chunked,
    797     retries=retries,
    798     response_conn=response_conn,
    799     preload_content=preload_content,
    800     decode_content=decode_content,
    801     **response_kw,
    802 )
    804 # Everything went great!

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:490, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    489         new_e = _wrap_proxy_error(new_e, conn.proxy.scheme)
--> 490     raise new_e
    492 # conn.request() calls http.client.*.request, not the method in
    493 # urllib3.request. It also calls makefile (recv) on the socket.

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:466, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
    465 try:
--> 466     self._validate_conn(conn)
    467 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1095, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1094 if conn.is_closed:
-> 1095     conn.connect()
   1097 # TODO revise this, see https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2791

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:730, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    728 server_hostname_rm_dot = server_hostname.rstrip(".")
--> 730 sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
    731     sock=sock,
    732     cert_reqs=self.cert_reqs,
    733     ssl_version=self.ssl_version,
    734     ssl_minimum_version=self.ssl_minimum_version,
    735     ssl_maximum_version=self.ssl_maximum_version,
    736     ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
    737     ca_cert_dir=self.ca_cert_dir,
    738     ca_cert_data=self.ca_cert_data,
    739     cert_file=self.cert_file,
    740     key_file=self.key_file,
    741     key_password=self.key_password,
    742     server_hostname=server_hostname_rm_dot,
    743     ssl_context=self.ssl_context,
    744     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    745     assert_hostname=self.assert_hostname,
    746     assert_fingerprint=self.assert_fingerprint,
    747 )
    748 self.sock = sock_and_verified.socket

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:909, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(sock, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ssl_minimum_version, ssl_maximum_version, cert_file, key_file, key_password, ca_certs, ca_cert_dir, ca_cert_data, assert_hostname, assert_fingerprint, server_hostname, ssl_context, tls_in_tls)
    907         server_hostname = normalized
--> 909 ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    910     sock=sock,
    911     keyfile=key_file,
    912     certfile=cert_file,
    913     key_password=key_password,
    914     ca_certs=ca_certs,
    915     ca_cert_dir=ca_cert_dir,
    916     ca_cert_data=ca_cert_data,
    917     server_hostname=server_hostname,
    918     ssl_context=context,
    919     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    920 )
    922 try:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:469, in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    467 context.set_alpn_protocols(ALPN_PROTOCOLS)
--> 469 ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    470 return ssl_sock

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    511     return SSLTransport(sock, ssl_context, server_hostname)
--> 513 return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dummy_folder\lib\ssl.py:513, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    507 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    508                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    509                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    510                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    511     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    512     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 513     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    514         sock=sock,
    515         server_side=server_side,
    516         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    517         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    518         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    519         context=self,
    520         session=session
    521     )

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dummy_folder\lib\ssl.py:1071, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1070             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1071         self.do_handshake()
   1072 except (OSError, ValueError):

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dummy_folder\lib\ssl.py:1342, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1341         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1342     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1343 finally:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 12
      4 polygon_coords = [
      5     (-74.0358, 40.7499), 
      6     (-74.0358, 40.7351), 
   (...)
      9     (-74.0358, 40.7499)  
     10 ]
     11 polygon = Polygon(polygon_coords)
---> 12 G=  ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type='drive',simplify=False)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\osmnx\graph.py:504, in graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type, simplify, retain_all, truncate_by_edge, clean_periphery, custom_filter)
    502 # create buffered graph from the downloaded data
    503 bidirectional = network_type in settings.bidirectional_network_types
--> 504 G_buff = _create_graph(response_jsons, retain_all=True, bidirectional=bidirectional)
    506 # truncate buffered graph to the buffered polygon and retain_all for
    507 # now. needed because overpass returns entire ways that also include
    508 # nodes outside the poly if the way (that is, a way with a single OSM
    509 # ID) has a node inside the poly at some point.
    510 G_buff = truncate.truncate_graph_polygon(G_buff, poly_buff, True, truncate_by_edge)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\osmnx\graph.py:632, in _create_graph(response_jsons, retain_all, bidirectional)
    629 paths = {}
    631 # consume response_jsons generator to download data from server
--> 632 for response_json in response_jsons:
    633     response_count += 1
    635     # if cache_only_mode, consume response_jsons then continue next loop

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\osmnx\_overpass.py:369, in _download_overpass_network(polygon, network_type, custom_filter)
    367 for polygon_coord_str in polygon_coord_strs:
    368     query_str = f"{overpass_settings};(way{osm_filter}(poly:{polygon_coord_str!r});>;);out;"
--> 369     yield _overpass_request(data={"data": query_str})

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\osmnx\_overpass.py:458, in _overpass_request(data, pause, error_pause)
    456 # transmit the HTTP POST request
    457 utils.log(f"Post {prepared_url} with timeout={timeout}")
--> 458 response = requests.post(
    459     url,
    460     data=data,
    461     timeout=timeout,
    462     headers=_downloader._get_http_headers(),
    463     **settings.requests_kwargs,
    464 )
    466 # handle 429 and 504 errors by pausing then recursively re-trying request
    467 if response.status_code in {429, 504}:  # pragma: no cover

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py:115, in post(url, data, json, **kwargs)
    103 def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    104     r"""Sends a POST request.
    105 
    106     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
    112     :rtype: requests.Response
    113     """
--> 115     return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py:59, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     55 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     56 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     57 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     "timeout": timeout,
    586     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:682, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    667     resp = conn.urlopen(
    668         method=request.method,
    669         url=url,
   (...)
    678         chunked=chunked,
    679     )
    681 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:
--> 682     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    684 except MaxRetryError as e:
    685     if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
    686         # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))


Running this on a Windows server (virtual machine). The issue is intermittent, so not sure if there is a firewall issue or a server issue.  I'm not sure if this is specific to my organization either. Any advice on why this is happening will be much appreciated!

It looks like things are timing out. Try on a different network connection or try on a different day?

Thanks @gboeing! This issue started after almost two years of successfully using the library. Could any firewall changes be the reason? My org has been going through some cyber security upgrades. Wondering if that is the cause of this timeout.

That would be a good question for your IT department. We can't answer that for you here.
